# Setting table header alignment based on first row alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I would like to set the alignment of a table's headers based on the alignment of the first `<td>` in each respective column.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
            <th>Third Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value One</td>
            <td align="right">Value Two</td>
            <td align="center">Value Three</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more rows -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, the second `<th>` would get aligned to the right and the third `<th>` would get centered. The first `<th>` would not be affected. Any suggestions/examples of how to accomplish this with jQuery would be very appreciated.

---

Based on InfernalBadger's answer, this is what I ended up using.  Turns out I needed to take into account the CSS `text-align` property as well as handling multiple tables.

```
function alignGridHeaders() {
    $('table.grid thead th').each(function (index) {
        var cell = $(this).parents('table:first').children('tbody tr:first td').eq(index);
        var alignment = cell.css('text-align');
        if (!alignment)
            alignment = cell.attr('align');
        if (alignment)
            $(this).css('text-align', alignment);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/KDyQt/)

```
$('#myTable th').each(function(index) {
    var alignment = $('#myTable tbody  tr:first td').eq(index).attr('align');
    if (alignment )
        $(this).css('text-align', alignment);   
});
```

I gave the table an ID of myTable for this example.

Answer (score 1):

Another, probably far less efficient, method. It does have the advantage of making blank or no align instructions left, but thats not much.

```
function toprowalign(){
    var pos = 1;
    $('table tr:nth-child(1) ').children('td').each(function(){
        var align = $(this).attr('align');
        if(align==''){align='left';}
        $('table tr th:nth-child('+pos+') ').attr('align',align);
        pos++;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the jQuery [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function. This will allow you to simply pass in the number of which element you'd like to modify. In your case, it would probably look something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#trID li').eq(2).css('align', 'right')
  $('#trID li').eq(3).css('align', 'center')

});
```

Hope this helps a bit!